# Can GraphEngine support RDF ?

Tags: graphengine

Does GraphEngine support RDF and SPARQL, as described in the paper:*A Distributed Graph Engine for Web Scale RDF Data* : https://www.graphengine.io/downloads/papers/Trinity.RDF.pdf

If not, could it be implemented on top of the engine, or is it in the roadmap?

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at our sample code for hosting Freebase:

https://github.com/Microsoft/GraphEngine/tree/master/samples/freebase-likq

The implementation is in `src/LIKQ`, and `samples/freebase-likq` provides an example of integrating an index service, multi-typed entity adapters with the LIKQ module.

The freebase dataset is imported as a Trinity image via `samples/GraphEngine.DataImporter` (currently in the `experimental` branch). It scans the data twice, first round to decide the data types for the entities and generates TSL storage layout schema, and the second round for the actual import work.